# SQL EXEC SP WITH PARAMETER INTO TEMP TABLE

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
SELECT * INTO #Temp FROM sp... PARAM1, PARAM2

Error : cannot use insert exec or cannot nested etc..
```

I wanna exec a sp with parameter and insert them to temp table.

any idea without using openrowset.

CREATE TABLE #TempStok (CODE VARCHAR(MAX), STOCKREF VARCHAR(MAX), AMOUNT INT )

INSERT INTO #TempStok EXEC spStokMiktar @ID_KULLANICI, @OTURUM, @SIRKETKOD  Error: An INSERT EXEC statement cannot be nested.

Comment: Does the stored proc always produce a single resultset, of the same format? If so, you could create the temporary table first, then use `INSERT #Temp EXEC ...`

Comment: Are you creating the schema for the `#temp` table?

Comment: Please tag your question with the RDBMS you're using, e.g. `sql-server-2008`

Comment: Re-tagged with `sql-server` due to the usage of `SELECT * INTO #Temp`

Answer (score 1):

What this error message is telling you is when attempting to 'bubble' up data from a chain of stored procedures, a restriction in SQL Server is you can only have one INSERT-EXEC active at a time. 
Here is an [article that discusses on how to solve this sort of problem.](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html#INSERTEXEC)

If you for some reason would try:

```
CREATE TABLE #BigSalesByStore(titleid varchar(80) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
                              qty     smallint    NOT NULL)
INSERT #BigSalesByStore (titleid, qty)
   EXEC BigSalesByStore '7131', 25
```

SQL Server will tell you:

```
Msg 8164, Level 16, State 1, Procedure BigSalesByStore, Line 8
An INSERT EXEC statement cannot be nested.
```

Provided that you may alter the procedure you are calling, there are two ways to alleviate the problem. One is simply to add a comment in the code of the callee, so that the next developer that comes around is made aware of the dependency and hopefully changes your procedure as well.
Another way is to use table types (if you are on SQL 2008 or later). Here is an example:

```
CREATE TYPE SalesByStore_tbl AS TABLE 
     (titleid varchar(80) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
      qty     smallint    NOT NULL)
go
CREATE PROCEDURE SalesByStore @storeid varchar(30) AS
   DECLARE @ret SalesByStore_tbl
   INSERT @ret (titleid, qty)
      SELECT t.title, s.qty
      FROM   sales s
      JOIN   titles t ON t.title_id = s.title_id
      WHERE  s.stor_id = @storeid
   SELECT * FROM @ret
go
CREATE PROCEDURE BigSalesByStore @storeid varchar(30),
                                 @qty     smallint AS
   DECLARE @data SalesByStore_tbl
   INSERT @data
      EXEC SalesByStore @storeid
   SELECT title, qty FROM @data WHERE qty >= @qty
go
EXEC SalesByStore '7131'
EXEC BigSalesByStore '7131', 25
go
DROP PROCEDURE SalesByStore, BigSalesByStore
DROP TYPE SalesByStore_tbl
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create the table and insert like this...

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp(field dataType, field2 dataType... )
```

You can then insert into this table like so...

```
Insert Into #Temp EXEC sp... PARAM1, PARAM2
```

However, I think it's more involved if the temp table isn't created as *design time*.